# Paypal donate button multiple currencies

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create a paypal donate button for my website but it only allows you to have one currency available, USD and I am trying to include a multiple currencies... how do I go about it to let people pay using all different types of currencies

This is the current code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="MNG6MMDEXT7KL">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Can I alter it somehow to include more currencies?
Also trying to figure out how I can grab the amount donated from a callback or something so I can update the amount donated on the website...

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a payment button on your website, you can convert the button to a different currency by adding one line of HTML code.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
```

**Sample Code**

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sales@@UKstore.com" >
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Union Jack Flag">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-butcc.gif" border="0" name="submit" width="73" height="44">
</form>
```

In addition, check it out [Currencies and Values](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_wa-outside)

Comment: I am trying to make it a drop down menu where a person can select the currency

Comment: Aliyasar's answer correctly shows how you can make a flexible button with whatever amount & currency you want. You can make the currency a drop-down simply by changing the input type from hidden to a select input (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

Comment: However, note that this answer presumes you are using plain html buttons, NOT hosted buttons as you did in your original question. Hosted buttons are intentionally "locked down" with specific payment details (such as amount and currency) so that users can NOT edit them. This is a convenience mechanism (some say security mechanism) to prevent users from "buying" a $5 item on your ecommerce store, for example, by sending you a $0.01 payment. You will need to enable and use regular (not hosted) buttons to get this flexible plain HTML form behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line (if you have it):

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

with this:

```
<select name="currency_code">
    <option value="AUD">AUD $</option>
    <option value="BRL">BRL R$</option>
    <option value="CAD">CAD $</option>
    <option value="CHF">CHF Fr.</option>
    <option value="CZK">CZK Kč</option>
    <option value="DKK">DKK kr.</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR €</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP £</option>
    <option value="HKD">HKD $</option>
    <option value="HUF">HUF Ft</option>
    <option value="ILS">ILS ₪</option>
    <option value="JPY">JPY ‎¥‎</option>
    <option value="MXN">‎MXN $‎</option>
    <option value="MYR">MYR RM</option>
    <option value="NOK">NOK kr</option>
    <option value="NZD">NZD $</option>
    <option value="PHP">‎PHP ₱</option>
    <option value="PLN">PLN gr</option>
    <option value="RUB">RUB ₽</option>
    <option value="SEK">SEK kr</option>
    <option value="SGD">SGD $</option>
    <option value="THB">THB ฿</option>
    <option value="TWD">TWD $</option>
    <option value="USD" selected>USD $</option>
</select>
```

This will give the user a dropdown box where they can select their currency.

Here's an example of what the full code could look like:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IE">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="BusinessName">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donate_SM.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://i1.wp.com/www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif?resize=1%2C1&#038;ssl=1"  data-recalc-dims="1">
    Currency: 
    <select name="currency_code">
        <option value="AUD">AUD $</option>
        <option value="BRL">BRL R$</option>
        <option value="CAD">CAD $</option>
        <option value="CHF">CHF Fr.</option>
        <option value="CZK">CZK Kč</option>
        <option value="DKK">DKK kr.</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR €</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP £</option>
        <option value="HKD">HKD $</option>
        <option value="HUF">HUF Ft</option>
        <option value="ILS">ILS ₪</option>
        <option value="JPY">JPY ‎¥‎</option>
        <option value="MXN">‎MXN $‎</option>
        <option value="MYR">MYR RM</option>
        <option value="NOK">NOK kr</option>
        <option value="NZD">NZD $</option>
        <option value="PHP">‎PHP ₱</option>
        <option value="PLN">PLN gr</option>
        <option value="RUB">RUB ₽</option>
        <option value="SEK">SEK kr</option>
        <option value="SGD">SGD $</option>
        <option value="THB">THB ฿</option>
        <option value="TWD">TWD $</option>
        <option value="USD" selected>USD $</option>
    </select>
</form>
```